# PHP check if string contains certain percentage of alphanumeric characters

Tags: php, alphanumeric, non-alphanumeric

I have a php string $comment sometimes the $comment box will contain some non alphanumeric characters, is there a way to find out what percentage of $comment is alphanumeric?

Thanks

Comment: My first thought is to use a regex to strip non-alpha characters, then compare the string length to the original string

Comment: Yup. Count them. Divide by the total number of characters. Multiply by 100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$comment_alpha = preg_replace('/[^a-z\d]+/i', '', $comment);
$alpha_percent = 100 * strlen($comment_alpha) / strlen($comment);
```

Comment: I'm curious: which of the two steps in this simple procedure were you having trouble doing yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this: (Not particularly efficient)

```
<?php
$string = "TestItOut##@22383";



$all = array(
"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",          
"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",     
"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"
);

$num_alphanum = 0;
foreach ( $all as $char ) {
    $num_alphanum += substr_count( $string, $char );
}

$percent = ( $num_alphanum / strlen( $string ) ) * 100;

echo $percent . "%";

?>
```

But Regex might be a simpler approach simpler